# MySQL - DELETE everything except

Tags: mysql

I have a table with object `varchar` and score `int`. I would like to DELETE all except the top 100 scoring items. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[mysql's delete](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) support both order by and limit so you should be find doing following:

```
select count(*) from t;
delete from t order by score asc limit resultFromPrevious-100;
```